# posting to a server with arguments

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

Hi i need to post some data to a web server from windows phone 7 app, i have following url

```
someurl/devices.json
```

and i need to send  two arguments with it

```
"externalDeviceId"  and "platform" as parameters
```

can any one let me know how to do it. i have been trying something like this

```
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
      client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
      client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      string argument = "externalDeviceId=123456789987654321"+"&platform=wp7"
      client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("someurl/devices.json"), "POST", argument);
```

but i get a web exception in the webClient_UploadStringCompleted callback.

i also tried something like this

soemurl/devices.json&externalDeviceId=123456789987654321&Platform=windowsphone7 but this is not working too get an error 404.

let me know where i am going wrong. this is on windows phone 7.

well  it worked, if i comment out the header and encoding line it works

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UploadStringCompleted += new 
UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
// client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 //client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
 string argument = "externalDeviceId=123456789987654321"+"&platform=wp7"
 client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("soemurl    
 /devices.json"), "POST", argument);
```

thanks Tetsujin no Oni san for helping ... i was going in circles from last one day and just some discussion and it helped fixing this problem

Comment: oops didnt knew i have to click the check mark to accept answer, corrected it on my previous posts. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your API URI as given, what happens if you make your arguments actually follow the correct protocol for query string parameters?

> http://api.maxchatter.com/75b7bb32e5fc752546263a/devices.json?externalDeviceId=123456789987654321&Platform=windowsphone7

Comment: if i use it as u suggested, then on fiddler i am getting 404 error. i am going to check on code and see what is the response i get

Comment: thanks Tetsuijin san problem is solved.. please see my edited response

Answer (score 0):

it works by using following code

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UploadStringCompleted += new 
UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
// client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
//client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string argument = "externalDeviceId=123456789987654321"+"&platform=wp7"
client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("soemurl    
/devices.json"), "POST", argument);
```